# Change the layout of a tree in D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hello i am very new t D3JS and I am writing a tree visualization. I am having difficulty on changing the layout of the tree from horizontal to vertical(top-to-bottom). I am able to successfully display the nodes vertically but the links are always horizontal. Any help would be appriciated. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
var m = [20, 120, 20, 120],
        w = 1280 - m[1] - m[3],
        h = 800 - m[0] - m[2],
        i = 0,
        root;


    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .size([h, w]);

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

    var vis = d3.select("#visualize")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
        .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

    d3.json("flare.json", function(json) {
      root = json;
      root.x0 = h / 2;
      root.y0 = 0;

      function toggleAll(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
          toggle(d);
        }
      }

      // Initialize the display to show a few nodes.
      root.children.forEach(toggleAll);

      update(root);
    });

    function update(source) {
      var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 5000 : 500;

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

      // Update the nodes…
      var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
          .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

      // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
          .on("click", function(d) { toggle(d); update(d); });

      nodeEnter.append("rect")
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -5 : -5; })
        .attr("width","9")
        .attr("height","9")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "skyblue" : "#fff"; })
        .style("stroke","green")
        .style("stroke-width", "1.5px");

      nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // Transition nodes to their new position.
      var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

      nodeUpdate.select("rect")
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -5 : -5; })
        .attr("width","9")
        .attr("height","9")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "skyblue" : "#fff"; })
        .style("stroke","green");

      nodeUpdate.select("text")
          .style("fill-opacity", 1);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
          .remove();

      nodeExit.select("circle")
          .attr("r", 1e-6);

      nodeExit.select("text")
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // Update the links…
      var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
          .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
          })
        .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", diagonal);

      // Transition links to their new position.
      link.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", diagonal);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      link.exit().transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
          })
          .remove();

      // Stash the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });
    }

    // Toggle children.
    function toggle(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3184089)?

Comment: Lars, yes I did, but it seems i cannot apply it to my example. I am not sure what i am missing

Comment: You mean changing `.projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; })` to `.projection(function (d) { return [d.x, d.y]; })` did not help?

Comment: Not really. I had to change more stuff on positioning the nodes too, except that one. Got it to work now. Will post my resolution soon.

Comment: @Leon Can you post your solution ?

Comment: @dev_marshell08 my answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved it @dev_marshell08

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var w = 1600,
        h = 2600,
        r = 6,
        fill = d3.scale.category20();
            var root;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-120)
        .linkDistance(30)
        .size([w, h]);

    var svg = d3.select("#visualize").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    d3.json("flare.json", function(json) {
        root = json;
    var nodes = flatten(root),
        links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

        var link = svg.selectAll("line")
                .data(links)
                .enter().append("svg:line")
                .attr("class", "link");

      var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("svg:circle")
          .attr("r", r - .75)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.group); })
          .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(fill(d.group)).darker(); })
          .call(force.drag);

      force
          .nodes(nodes)
          .links(links)
          .on("tick", tick)
          .start();

      function tick(e) {

        // Push sources up and targets down to form a weak tree.
        var k = 6 * e.alpha;
        links.forEach(function(d, i) {
          d.source.y -= k;
          d.target.y += k;
        });

        node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
      }
    });

  function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [], i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
      if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
      if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
      nodes.push(node);
    }

    recurse(root);
    return nodes;
  }
</script>
```